# How to download large dataset in docker file?

Tags: docker

I use docker to serve website, after executing

```
python3 app.py
```

the docker need to download dataset first then launch website:
[image: the first time]

due to slow speed of downloading, I stoped and executed again with following way:

```
sudo docker start webapp_ner && sudo docker exec -it webapp_ner bash
```

the second and third time, the code continued to download at the last time place, but at the fourth time, nearly finished, I found the docker download from beginning
[image: the fourth time]

because the bandwidth so narrow, I can't download once in one day, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd download the file in the Dockerfile and bake it into the image.

Alternatively, you could download the file to a volume or local filesystem and mount it in the Docker container when you run it.

Either way, it will only download a build time, rather than runtime.