# Downloading Large Files Inside A Docker Container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, containers, kubernetes-pod

A simple problem that I am facing. I am using docker to build a simple image which downloads a file using curl or wget after container is loaded. The file that I am downloading is about 7GB and need 7GB more to extract it in the same container. Below is the code for the image I am building.

```
FROM node:alpine3.15 as builder

RUN apk update
RUN apk add wget
RUN apk add unzip

COPY package.json ./
COPY index.js ./
ADD startCensusLoad.sh .

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","startProcess.sh"]
```

And this is my startProcess.sh file code.

```
wget --continue zip_file_download_link_goes_here;
unzip downloaded_zip_file.zip;
npm start;
```

When I build the image and start a container, the download starts as expected but stops at multiple points like 2 GB or 4 GB or 1.8 GB and so on. I have not been able to download the full file in the container yet. I have also tried curl and seeing the same behavior. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue. The container would run in a kube environment later on so that I can assign an ephemeral volume but for now I am trying to download full file in the container itself.

Comment: Isn't close to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287837/how-to-download-large-dataset-in-docker-file?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by doing more search on the census website. I was able to find that census.gov does provide that 7GB data in States level and I was able to use download a chunk at a time and process it. So basically container size did not exceed more than the largest state data.